# sugarcrm disabling search page for module

Tags: sugarcrm

I have two custom modules: `cm_product, cm_item`

with one to many relationship: `cm_product -> cm_item`

I want to disable the search page for `cm_item`, so the only way to see the items for customer is through it's parent reference: `cm_product`.

I need to accomplish it through the code.

This is my temporary solution if somebody interested in, file - `custom/modules/cm_item/views/view.list.php`:

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once 'include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php';

class cm_itemViewList extends ViewList
{
    public function preDisplay() { }
    public function display() {
        echo <<<HTML
        <h1>Por favor seleccione la Oportunidad para ver sus correspondientes ventas e items.</h1>
HTML;
    }
    function prepareSearchForm(){ }
    function listViewProcess(){ }
}
```

SugarCRM Versión 6.5.11 (Build 8754) Pro edition.

Answer (score 2):

it can be possible via add the blank array line at the end of file i.e.
custom/modules/cm_item/metadata/searchdefs.php

```
$searchdefs[$module_name] = array();
```

Comment: It's wont work. Actually the $searchdefs is empty array when I did var_dump of it on this file. I even tried the `global $searchdef;` Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really just need the module tab for cm_item that links to the search and list view to not be displayed so that cm_items are only accessible through the subpanel of a cm_product. To do that you don't need code (unless you are doing it in a distributable module). Simply drag the cm_item module to the Hidden Modules list in Admin->Display Modules and Subpanels. If you are mass distributing the module then you would set tab to true in the beans definition in your manifest.php (see http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/Module_Loader/Introduction_to_the_Manifest_File#tab)

Comment: I need to acomplish the same through the code, without manifest, or Admin menu. Thank you any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the top module menu link by making sure the module isn't listed in the global array $moduleList

Comment: This will not disable the list, and you will still have the access to the list once you are in DetailView